# `dispatcher` object or `request` object

Tags: php, phalcon

Which time should we get request parameters from `dispatcher` object and which time should we  get request parameters from `request` object?

```
public function saveAction(){
    $email = $this->request->getPost("user_email")
}
```

or

```
public function saveAction(){
    $email = $this->dispatcher->getParam("email") 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Request is the abstraction of the HTTP request and the Dispatcher is something else, dispatching an action. Use what is more fitting in your case.

It's normally wise inside higher-level functions to not rely on the concrete request but just on the dispatcher that is designed to work together with the action.

Answer (score 1):

I use Request when I need to get querystring or post parameters and I use Dispatcher when I need to get some route parameter.
Thanks,